# How to solve an array with react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this array and I need to fetch it with react, but I will receive the `item.slug` through the url, if I receive the slug-one, I only need to solve the array inside the slug-one and so on.
How can I do this with react?

```
[{
    "slug": "slug-one",
    "id": 1,
    "page": [{
      "title": "lorem ipsum title",
      "description": "lorem description",
      "text": "Lorem text"        
    }]
},
{
    "slug": "slug-two",
    "id": 2,
    "page": [{
        "title": "lorem ipsum title another title",
        "description": "lorem description two",
        "text": "Lorem text my text"        
      }]
}]
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by slugs, but that looks like JSON, so just use `JSON.parse(data)` and it will parse to a javascript array.

Comment: Check out this article: https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-fetch-data-from-an-api-with-react-hooks-9e7202b8afcd

Comment: Use `.filter(element => element.slug === props.match.params.id)` on your array. `props.match` will come from `react-router`'s `Route` component.